How do I "go back" after installing a locally built package
I have looked around on instruction on how to download debian source package, build them and then installing the resultin deb-file(s), but the one I feel is missing is instruction on how to reverse it and go back to use the official (binary) package(s), as fetched from the debian repository.

You can revert to the repository’s binary package by specifying the repository’s code name; for example, on Debian 12,
sudo apt install package/bookworm

(replacing package as appropriate).
You can also use stable etc.:
sudo apt install package/stable

